# iOS automated tests questions

Tags: ios, unit-testing, automated-tests

I've been working on a project that I want to add automated tests. I already added some unit tests, but I'm not confident with the process that I've been using, I do not have a great experience with automated tests so I would like to ask for some advice.

The project is integrated with our web API, so it has a login process. According to the logged user the API provides a configuration file which will allow / disallow the access to some modules and permissions within the mobile application. We also have a sync process where the app will access several methods from the API to download files (PDFs, html, videos, etc) and also receive a lot of data through JSON files. The user basically doesn't have to insert data, just use the information received in the sync process.

What I did to add unit tests in this scenario so far was to simulate a logged user, then I added some fixture objects to the user and test them. 
I was able to test the web service integration, I used Nocilla to return fake JSONs and assert the result. So far I was only able to test individual request, but I still don't know how should I test the sync process.

I'm having a hard time to create unit tests for my view controllers. Should I unit test just the business logic and do all the rest with tools like KIF / Calabash?

Is there an easy way to setup the fixture data and files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everybody's mileage may vary but here's what we settled on and why.

Unit tests: We use a similar strategy.  Only difference is we use OHTTPStubs instead of Nocilla because we saw some more flexibility there that we needed and were happy to trade off the easier syntax of Nocilla.

Doing more complicated (non-single query) test cases quickly lost its luster because we were essentially rebuilding whole HTTP request/response flows and that wasn't very "unit".  For functional tests, we did end up adopting KIF (at least for dev focused efforts, assuming you don't have a seaparte QA department) for a few reasons:

- We didn't buy/need the multi-language abstraction layer afforded by
  Appium.
- We wanted to be able to run tests on many devices per
  build server.
- We wanted more whitebox testing and while
  Subliminal was attractive, we didn't want to build hooks in our main
  app code.

Testing view controller logic (anything that's not unit-oriented) is definitely much more useful using KIF/Calbash or something similar so that's the path I would suggest.

For bonus points, here are some other things we did.  Goes to show what you *could* do I guess:

- We have a basic proof of concept that binds KIF commands to a JSON RPC server.  So you can run a test target on a device and have that device respond to HTTP requests, which will then fire off test cases or KIF commands.  One of the advantage of this is that you can reuse some of the test code you wrote for single device for multiple device test cases.
- Our CI server builds integration tests as a downstream build of our main build (which includes unit tests).  When the build starts we use XCTool to precompile tests, and then we have some scripts that starts recording a quicktime screen recording, runs the KIF tests, exports the result, and then archive it on our CI server so we can see a live test run along with test logs.

Not really part of this answer but happy to share that if you ping me.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I think I'll create the functional  tests with KIF/Calabash for my view controllers and views instead of trying to test everything with unit test as I was doing before. I guess my biggest difficulty now is to prepare the scenario before the tests being executed. Is there any website link or a blog post  about the KIF + JSON RPC server solution that you find out?

Comment: We rolled our own on the KIF + JSON RPC server but the basic idea is to make a test target that has a single test that waits forever and then set up your http endpoints there and use dynamic dispatch to trigger methods (kind of like Frank, except with KIF).  I can give you sample code if you ping me your contact info.

Comment: Cool! I would like to know more about this. My email address is franco2610 at gmail.com. Thanks!

Comment: Put up the details here: https://medium.com/@lukesma/remote-controlling-your-ios-device-with-kif-e223b3156698

Medium isn't the greatest platform for writing about code, he realizes aftewards.